ERROR in NSCF calculation execution in QE
    Atomic positions and unit cell read from directory:
     ./VsubG(1)_SCF.save/
     Message from routine qes_read:magnetizationType:
     do_magnetization: wrong number of occurrences
     Message from routine qexsd_readschema :
application called MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1) - process 0
     error reading output_obj of xsd data file

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine read_conf_from_file (4):
     fatal error reading xml file
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...
[unset]: PMIU_write error; fd=-1 buf=:cmd=abort exitcode=1 message=application called MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1) - process 0
:
system msg for write_line failure : Bad file descriptor

This error keeps arising while executing the nscf file. Prefix is also the same one used in previous scf calculation. Can anyone please tell me what the way of correcting it is?
input file - nscf
 &CONTROL
    calculation = 'nscf',
    prefix      = 'VsubG(1)_SCF',
    ! otudir      = '/tmp',
    pseudo_dir  = './', 
    
 /

 &SYSTEM
    ibrav     = 0,
    celldm(1) = 37.18980746,
    nat  = 128,
    ntyp = 2,
    nspin = 2,
    starting_magnetization(1)=0.2,
    starting_magnetization(2)=0.5,
    ecutwfc = 60,
    ecutrho = 480, 

    occupations = 'smearing',
    smearing = 'mv',
    degauss = 0.01,
 /
 
 &ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-8
    
 /

 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   C  12.0107 C.pbe-rrkjus.UPF
   V  50.9415 v_pbe_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF

CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=37.18980746)
   1.006429445  -0.000000000  -0.000000000
  -0.503214722   0.871593466   0.000000000
   0.000000000  -0.000000000   1.016151153
   
ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
C            -0.0026055364        0.0015043071        0.0000000000
C             1.2327643591        0.7020876536        0.0000000000
C            -1.2469757130        2.1403880175       -0.0000000000
C            -0.0113438331        2.8469185999       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4844980081        4.2832277564       -0.0000000000
C            -1.2549768910        4.9930920828        0.0000000000
C            -3.7214909369        6.4263740014        0.0000000000
C            -2.4918010686        7.1431965183        0.0000000000
C            -4.9516328938        8.5734710734        0.0000000000
C            -3.7272249094        9.2930411458        0.0000000000
C            -6.1803924137       10.7218719654        0.0000000000
C            -4.9516327855       11.4391482100       -0.0000000000
C            -7.4172411112       12.8706130513       -0.0000000000
C            -6.1853533785       13.5818437848        0.0000000000
C            -8.6596806998       15.0161253482       -0.0000000000
C            -7.4241219299       15.7216250654       -0.0000000000
C             2.4723450979       -0.0085592011       -0.0000000000
C             3.7112647190        0.6977112124       -0.0000000000
C             1.2215082749        2.1220060104        0.0000000000
C             2.4568015926        2.8177366258       -0.0000000000
C            -0.0190876652        4.2742909637        0.0000000000
C             1.2135957239        4.9767858369       -0.0000000000
C            -1.2595323247        6.4228045176        0.0000000000
C            -0.0348122067        7.1390917097       -0.0000000000
C            -2.5031682288        8.5733341781       -0.0000000000
C            -1.2830006838        9.2952641019       -0.0000000000
C            -3.7228728641       10.7218722978       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4917648229       11.4416734664       -0.0000000000
C            -4.9516323557       12.8666285260       -0.0000000000
C            -3.7179121052       13.5818438288       -0.0000000000
C            -6.1878874350       15.0078847482       -0.0000000000
C            -4.9516327037       15.7187106725        0.0000000000
C             4.9516330483       -0.0117872973       -0.0000000000
C             6.1920012999        0.6977111799        0.0000000000
C             3.7054686649        2.1159946131       -0.0000000000
C             4.9516329402        2.8200896189       -0.0000000000
C             2.4367175373        4.2320324151        0.0000000000
C             3.6739426829        4.9135684636        0.0000000000
C             1.2092164432        6.4157951672       -0.0000000000
C             2.4312878614        7.1213579320       -0.0000000000
C            -0.0682267015        8.5707228278        0.0000000000
C             1.1406134164        9.3014233231        0.0000000000
C            -1.2663940598       10.7275120420        0.0000000000
C            -0.0335472154       11.4546747712       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4860244966       12.8706131875       -0.0000000000
C            -1.2513965588       13.5900543165        0.0000000000
C            -3.7153776081       15.0078845566       -0.0000000000
C            -2.4791436040       15.7216250868       -0.0000000000
C             7.4309217664       -0.0085591453       -0.0000000000
C             8.6705014163        0.7020875750        0.0000000000
C             6.1977978675        2.1159948614        0.0000000000
C             7.4464642593        2.8177364986       -0.0000000000
C             4.9516334813        4.2311188884       -0.0000000000
C             6.2293231142        4.9135683663       -0.0000000000
C             3.6567563056        6.3175028157       -0.0000000000
C             4.9516328197        6.8371586114        0.0000000000
C             2.3478626964        8.5845723805        0.0000000000
C             3.4453365161        9.4461403058       -0.0000000000
C             1.1884401333       10.7491600476       -0.0000000000
C             2.4183035495       11.5144475568       -0.0000000000
C            -0.0202292404       12.8859328205       -0.0000000000
C             1.2118305414       13.6164385437        0.0000000000
C            -1.2435844809       15.0161257375       -0.0000000000
C            -0.0083564349       15.7343102904       -0.0000000000
C             9.9058712705        0.0015043379       -0.0000000000
C            11.1434634086        0.7160284052        0.0000000000
C             8.6817580326        2.1220057571       -0.0000000000
C             9.9146095672        2.8469185003       -0.0000000000
C             7.4665484379        4.2320323450        0.0000000000
C             8.6896700858        4.9767856917       -0.0000000000
C             6.2465101092        6.3175024879       -0.0000000000
C             7.4719779053        7.1213578189       -0.0000000000
V             4.9516328938        8.5764796876       -0.0000000000
C             6.4579290958        9.4461402897        0.0000000000
C             3.6427393176       10.8273644845        0.0000000000
C             4.9516327855       11.4867233965       -0.0000000000
C             2.4466886830       12.9266840539        0.0000000000
C             3.7032248494       13.6135618115       -0.0000000000
C             1.2269564237       15.0340995948       -0.0000000000
C             2.4711755500       15.7393241751        0.0000000000
C            12.3803828607        0.0097186907       -0.0000000000
C            13.6174008811        0.7215148920       -0.0000000000
C            11.1502408739        2.1403877643       -0.0000000000
C            12.3851835872        2.8557780423        0.0000000000
C             9.9223533993        4.2742903740       -0.0000000000
C            11.1582425496        4.9930919375       -0.0000000000
C             8.6940489601        6.4157947676       -0.0000000000
C             9.9380779408        7.1390915219        0.0000000000
C             7.5554031459        8.5845717256       -0.0000000000
C             8.7626522648        9.3014231608       -0.0000000000
C             6.2605259601       10.8273641520        0.0000000000
C             7.4849619649       11.5144474888       -0.0000000000
C             4.9516323556       12.8978496706       -0.0000000000
C             6.2000406342       13.6135617675       -0.0000000000
C             3.7111876961       15.0323441406       -0.0000000000
C             4.9516327036       15.7432552367       -0.0000000000
C            14.8548984200        0.0100245141       -0.0000000000
C            16.0923960368        0.7215149245       -0.0000000000
C            13.6200842770        2.1459068920        0.0000000000
C            14.8548985281        2.8588266065       -0.0000000000
C            12.3877635012        4.2832276863        0.0000000000
C            13.6226811917        4.9991867744       -0.0000000000
C            11.1627983897        6.4228041180        0.0000000000
C            12.3950667702        7.1431964052       -0.0000000000
C             9.9714924356        8.5707226125        0.0000000000
C            11.1862664710        9.2952639396        0.0000000000
C             8.7148260340       10.7491595885        0.0000000000
C             9.9368129495       11.4546746867       -0.0000000000
C             7.4565769246       12.9266839176        0.0000000000
C             8.6914350275       13.6164385051       -0.0000000000
C             6.1920773468       15.0323443321        0.0000000000
C             7.4320899837       15.7393241536        0.0000000000
C            17.3294132119        0.0097186349        0.0000000000
C            18.5663337528        0.7160284838        0.0000000000
C            16.0897121274        2.1459066437        0.0000000000
C            17.3246134978        2.8557781695        0.0000000000
C            14.8548979872        4.2846669826        0.0000000000
C            16.0871159481        4.9991868716        0.0000000000
C            13.6247559905        6.4263736736        0.0000000000
C            14.8548986487        7.1444228103        0.0000000000
C            12.4064338549        8.5733335232        0.0000000000
C            13.6304907658        9.2930411299        0.0000000000
C            11.1696593608       10.7275115828       -0.0000000000
C            12.3950307768       11.4416733984       -0.0000000000
C             9.9234949745       12.8859321078       -0.0000000000
C            11.1546624582       13.5900542779       -0.0000000000
C             8.6763087568       15.0340992054        0.0000000000
C             9.9116221690       15.7343103289        0.0000000000

K_POINTS automatic
   20 20 1   0 0 0


Clearly the issue is with specifying magnetization... from the pw.x documentation: "starting_magnetization is ignored in most BUT NOT ALL cases in non-scf calculations: it is safe to keep the same values for the scf and subsequent non-scf calculation." Maybe try removing starting_magnetization from your input file? This should be read from the density files anyway.

@TylerSterling Thank you for your contribution. I tried running it after removing starting_magnetization. Unfortunately, it still shows this error. Is there anything else I can test based on your expertise?

I guess the problem was that <do_magnetization>false</do_magnetization> was missing in the data-file-schema.xml file created after the SCF calculation. I am not sure why it is missing from the XML. However, after I manually added this code block, it started to run without errors. I will include several code blocks to track where to insert <do_magnetization>false</do_magnetization> in the .xml file.
</basis_set>
    <dft>
      <functional>PBE</functional>
    </dft>
    <magnetization>
      <lsda>true</lsda>
      <noncolin>false</noncolin>
      <spinorbit>false</spinorbit>
      <total>8.948687658132513e-1</total>
      <absolute>1.733424503007940e0</absolute>
      <do_magnetization>false</do_magnetization>
    </magnetization>
    <total_energy>


Glad you got it sorted out! If this is a real error and you are using the latest version of QE, I suggest submitting a bug report.
